# How to lock particular test case in Test plan module when some one is working in Particular TC

Tags: test-management, quality-center, hp-alm

If a user is working on a particular test case in Test plan module.He is copying that test case to some other project but he wants to make sure no other person should work on it or just a information (a flag set ) to show that he is working on particular test case. How could it be achievable?

Comment: In which tool you are trying to achieve this or your question is in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a clean and bullet-proof way **only if you enable (and license) the version control support in QC/ALM. Then, your user could check out the test, guaranteeing that nobody else can modify it.**

For the cross-project work you outlined, QC also has features in the release manager module, but for those to work really good you also need to enable (and license) version control.